# SMF curl login issue php

Tags: php, curl, authentication, forum

Does any one have have some PHP login curl code for SMF version  1.1.11
I tried and it logs then when I check the curl output, but when the broswer loads, they are no longer logged in

My code

```
function login($data)
{
    if(function_exists('curl_init' )) {

        $_SESSION['old_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'test';
        // smf needs this sigh
        // create a new cURL resource
        $data = array( 'noverify'=>1 , 'user'=> $data['username'] ,  'passwrd' => $data['password'] ,'hash_passwrd'=>$data['password'], 'cookielength'=>'60');
        $ch = curl_init();
        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/forum/index.php?action=login2");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        $a = curl_exec($ch);

        //$ch_temp=curl_copy_handle($ch);

        //print_r($ch_temp);
        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close ($ch); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's to be expected. Your script and your browser do not use the same cookie. It's like if you logged in with Firefox and expected that when you open Chrome you'll be logged in as well.